# Linux Symlink Traversal Issue

Tags: linux, symlink, path, usb-drive

I am trying to use a USB PENDRIVE to increase my current path for building a large library.

So, I have this idea of creating a symlink in my program to a folder in the Pendrive. So that it uses the space in the Pen Drive instead of my main storage.

`/home/me/opencv/`   <-- this is the product I want to build
`/home/me/opencv/build/`    <-- this is the build folder.

At this point there is not enough memory to build it there, so I created this symlink in `/home/me/opencv/`

```
mkdir /media/me/pendrive/opencv/build/

ln -s /media/me/pendrive/opencv/build/  /home/me/opencv/ -s
```

this created a link "build" under `/home/me/opencv/` folder that points to my pen drive.

The problem here is that directory traversal points to the pen drive too.

```
cd /home/me/opencv
ls
```

this renders a number of folders and files inside opencv folder

But if I do...

```
cd /home/me/opencv/build
ls ..
```

this renders an empty opencv folder with an only folder named build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a *bind* mount, assuming you can use *sudo* or have root rights. For example,

```
mkdir /home/me/opencv/build
mkdir -p /media/me/pendrive/opencv/build
sudo mount -o bind /home/me/opencv/build /media/me/pendrive/opencv/build
```

Then, when in `/home/me/opencv/build`, you should see in `..` the contents of `/home/me/opencv/`.  Use `sudo umount /home/me/opencv/build` to undo the mount.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between *logical* and *physical* directory paths that you've run into.

```
cd /home/me/opencv/build
```

This will place you in the logical directory `/home/me/opencv/build`, but physically, you're actually in `/media/me/pendrive/opencv/build`, thanks to the symbolic link.

`ls ..` will show you the contents of the *physical* parent directory `/media/me/pendrive/opencv`.

A physical directory path is a logical directory path with all its symbolic links resolved. They are the same if the logical directory path does not contain only symbolic links.

See also the difference between `pwd -L` and `pwd -P` while in that build directory (and read the `pwd` manual).

`cd` also has `-L` and `-P` flags (and `-L` is the default).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

It sounds to me that there is no way to create a symlink that works the way I want (where `ls ..` will list the contents of `/home/me/opencv/` folder)